# Ferromagnetic substance beyond Curie's temperature

Tags: electromagnetism, ferromagnetism

According to my textbook and various sources on internet I found that susceptibility of paramagnetic substance is related to temperature by the following formula: $$χ=Cμ_0/T$$

Susceptibility of ferromagnetic substance beyond Curie's temperature is related to temperature by the following formula: $$χ=C/(T-T_c)$$

Why there is no $μ_0$ in second formula?

Comment: Does C have to be same in both equations?

Comment: One is defined with B, the other with H. You just have to get used to different people using different conventions.